# Bezier-Model suddenly not showing anymore in Unity

Tags: unity, bezier-curves

I'm new to Blender, taking an online course at the moment. So far we created a simple landscape which has some lamps. The lamps were made with a Bezier that wraps around an axis (sorry, i only know the german expression of the method, "Drehmaschine", at least the course called it so).

At first it worked, it showed up in Unity. Now, in a later stage of the course, we got back to those lamps. I didn't like the form anymore and wanted to improve it, so i played around a bit with the position of the Bezier, until i liked it.

I saved it, exported it to Unity, and suddenly all lamps are invisible. I have no clue what went wrong. I tried to "undo" what i did, again played around a bit, but nothing worked so far.

I already know from normal meshes about the problem with the normals, but i don't have them here.
I'll add a picture of it, maybe someone knows what to do. Thanks in advance! :)

[image]

Comment: This is typical. I try forever on my own, finally make a post somewhere to get help, and 5 minutes later i find it out myself :D
The problem was that i didn't convert the curve to a mesh again.

Comment: if you want to post your own answer, you can

Comment: That’s sometimes called “magic feather,” but it’s really truth: just the faith that someone can and has been asked to help has amazing effectiveness.

Comment: The problem was that i didn't convert the curve to a mesh again.

Comment: Ah, this is how it works with answers. Quite new to the site. Thanks Allen!